# Regex match string 3-6 characters long, at least one letter, no duplicate "-"

Tags: regex

I have to match a string that is 3-6 characters long, contains at least one letter, but can have letters, numbers and only 1 "-".
The "-" must not be at the start or at the beginning.

Match:

```
string
str-ng
st-ng
s1-1g
st-1g
```

Do not match:

```
strings
-string
string-
st--ng
s-tn-g
1111
st
```

The closest I've gotten is this:

```regex
^((?!-.*-)[0-9A-Z]{3,6})$
```

But this divides the regex match with `-` So it matches `s-tri` but not `st-ri` because there aren't 3 chars at each end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?!-|.*-$|.*-.*-)[a-z\d-]{3,6}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ysmme1/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - Positive lookahead to make sure there is at least one letter.
- `(?!-|.*-$|.*-.*-)` - Negative lookahead to prevent a hyphen at the beginning **or** at the end **or** multiple.
- `[a-z\d-]{3,6}` - Three to six times a character from the give class.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Note that I used the case-insensitive flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
^(?=.{3,6}$)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[A-Za-z])[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1iWeIL/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{3,6}$)` - string must contain three to six chars other than line break chars
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[A-Za-z])` - there must be at least one ASCII letter in the string
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` - one or more alphanumeric ASCII chars
- `(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?` - an optional sequence of `-` and then one or more alphanumeric ASCII chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pattern that you tried, you meant to exclude the match when there are 2 hyphens present using the negative lookahead.

Also this part `[0-9A-Z]{3,6}` does not match a hyphen.

Reading

> The "-" must not be at the start or at the beginning.

You might do that using

```
^(?![^\n-]*-[^\n-]*-)(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ljrNfZ/1)

If you meant also no `-` at the end:

```
^(?![^\n-]*-[^\n-]*-)(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,4}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![^\n-]*-[^\n-]*-)` Assert not 2 times `-`
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z\n]*[a-zA-Z])` Assert a char a-zA-Z
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` Match One of the listed without `-`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,4}` Repeat 1-4 times any of the listed including `-`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` Match One of the listed without `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8enW7s/1)